# What insect is this

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Saw many of these on my broccoli plant. Never saw them in the garden before today

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I guess you live in North America?
Your broccoli is infested with the harlequin cabbage bug (Murgantia histrionica)
You took a picture of one of the nymphs.
Link to Wikipedia: [Harlequin cabbage bug](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harlequin_cabbage_bug)

To get rid of them, according to Wikipedia:
Handpick every bug and nymph off your plants.
Search carefully for eggs, which are black and white striped and come in packets of a dozen
[image: 2]]
[image: 3]]
[image: 4]]
[image: 5]]

Comment: Some excellent photographs! Garden pest or not, it's a delightful-looking creature.